# VB NET, Entity EF6 - Query Expression binded to DataGridView with Select New Class not showing data

Tags: vb.net, class, entity

In WinForms, EF6 I have the code below:

```
Public Class invoice_class
        Public ID As Integer
        Public Name As String
End Class 

Private Sub Button_Query_List_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Query_List.Click
        Dim db As New base_Entities

        Dim l1 = (From invoice In db._invoices
                 Select invoice.ID, invoice.Name).ToList

        Dim l2 = (From invoices In db._invoices
                 Select New invoice_class() With {
                        .ID = invoices.ID,
                        .Name = invoices.Name}).ToList

        DataGridView1.DataSource = l1   'this working - data shows on DataGridView
        DataGridView1.DataSource = l2   'this not working - data not shows on DataGridView

        For Each n In l2
                 MessageBox.Show(n.Name.ToString)   'but this showing a data
        Next
End Sub
```

In the code I make the comment with problem. Why using query `l2` I don't see any data in `DataGridView1` but I see in `For ... Next` loop?

Thank you.

**- EDIT (solution) -**

**Anu6is** correctly suggested that Property should be used when declaring the class.
The corrected part of the code:

```
Public Class invoice_class
        Property ID As Integer
        Property Name As String
End Class
```

Comment: Your data source does not know what to do with your invoice_class object. In your for loop you are extracting the name property from the invoice_class. In your first list, you don't use the invoice_class, your list contains an anonymous class

Comment: Thanks, I understand that but why datasource know what to do with anonymous class, but don`t know what to do with invoice_class object? How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try using Properties instead of fields for you class and it should be recognized.

Comment: OT, don't use silly names like `invoice_class`. Do you see the .NET Framework using `string_class`? Of course not. The class is named `String`, as yours should be named `Invoice`.

Comment: "Anu6is" thank`s for your help.